# Is this the correct way to save form values in MVC3?

Tags: view, controller, asp.net-mvc-3

Here's my code:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Register()
{
    RegisterViewModel model = new RegisterViewModel();
    using (CityRepository city = new CityRepository())
    {
        model.SelectCityList = new SelectList(city.FindAllCities().ToList(), "CityID", "CityName");
    }

    using (CountryRepository country = new CountryRepository())
    {
        model.SelectCountryList = new SelectList(country.FindAllCountries().ToList(), "CountryID", "CountryName");
    }

    return View(model);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Register(RegisterViewModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        //Actually register the user here.
        RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }            

    //Something went wrong, redisplay the form for correction.
    return View(model);
}
```

Is this the best approach or is there another better tested way? Keep in mind that my database tables/field names are nothing like what I declared in my models. I have to scrape the values from the ViewModel and put them into an entity framework generated class to persist the information.

Anything here that screams out at you as wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I use that pattern and another pattern which looks like this (important part is the AutoMapper part):

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Register(RegisterViewModel model)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        // repopulate any input or other items set in GET
        // prefer to do at top due to ^^^ is easy to overlook
        return View(model);
    }

    // if it's an edit, pull to new instance
    // from the database and use automapper to
    // map over the submitted values from model to instance
    // then update instance in database
    //
    // VALUE: useful if form only shows
    // some of the properties/fields of model
    // (otherwise, those not shown would be null/default)

    // if it's new, insert

    RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That's the pattern I generally use.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer this pattern: 
Controller:

```
 [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var cities= (from m in db.cities select m);
            ViewBag.Cities= cities;

            var states = (from m in db.States select m);
            ViewBag.States = states;

            return View();
        }
        [HttpPost]
         public ActionResult Index(RegisterViewModel model)
             {
             if (ModelState.IsValid)
                { 
                  // Saving the data
                  return View("ActionName", model);
                }
        return View();
    }
```

View:

```
@Html.DropDownList("DDLCities",new SelectList(ViewBag.Cities, "CityId" , "CityName" ), new { @class = "className" })
@Html.DropDownList("DDLStates",new SelectList(ViewBag.States, "StateId" , "StateName" ), new { @class = "className" })
```

Answer (score 0):

Advised changes to `[HttpGet]`:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Register()
{
    // Get
    var cities = new List<City>();
    var countries = new List<Country>();

    using (CityRepository city = new CityRepository())
    {
       cities = city.FindAllCities().ToList();
    }

    using (CountryRepository country = new CountryRepository())
    {
       counties = country.FindAllCountries().ToList();
    }

    // Map.
    var aggregatedObjects = new SomePOCO(cities, countries);
    var model = Mapper.Map<SomePOCO,RegisterViewModel>(aggregatedObjects );

    // Return
    return View(model);
}
```

**Summary of changes:**

- Layout your logic in such a way the controller's job makes sense. Get - Map - Return. Exactly the tasks (in order) for which a Controller is designed for.
- Use AutoMapper to do the heavy lifting of ViewModel creation for you.

Advised changes to your `[HttpPost]`:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Register(RegisterViewModel model)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid) 
      return View(model);

    try
    {
       var dbObj = Mapper.Map<RegisterViewModel,SomeDomainObj>(model);
       _repository.Save(dbObj);
       return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    catch (Exception exc)
    {
       if (exc is BusinessError)
          ModelState.AddModelError("SomeKey", ((BusinessError)exc).FriendlyError);
       else
          ModelState.AddModelError("SomeKey", Resources.Global.GenericErrorMessage);
    }

    return View(model);
}
```

**Summary of changes:**

- Try/catch. Always need to capture exceptions, whether they are domain exceptions or lower-level (database ones)
- Check ModelState validity first. As @Cymen says - do it first so you don't forget later
- Add exceptions to ModelState. Use custom exception classes for business errors with descriptive, resource-based messages. If the error is too low-level for the user (foreign key constraint, etc), show a generic message